# How to provide Access control to the users in openLdap?

Tags: ldap, openldap

How can I give access rights to the users in my ldap server so that they can authenticate. 
I referred this tutorial http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html and added following lines

```
access to *
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by * read
```

in my slapd.conf.

Yet I get insufficient access rights when I try to bind users with their username and userPassword. What is the correct way to provide access to the users so that they can bind to the server and  can modify their self details.

This is my code to bind -

```
require 'net/ldap'
con = Net::LDAP.new
con.host = 'localhost'
con.port = 389
con.auth 'cn=user,dc=example,dc=com', 'user'

if con.bind
  puts con.get_operation_result
else

  puts con.get_operation_result 
end
```

Comment: Most likely, your primary problem is that you configured this  that you configured this with the old deprecated static configuration config files and not with the dynamic configuration method. Read section 8.3 in your link.

Comment: Yeah, I used static configuration. Even if its deprecated is it not supposed to work ?

Comment: Your current ACL allows all authenticated users to read all directory information. This includes `userPassword` from other users. That is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Please show the code/command used to attempt the bind.

Comment: This is my code to bind - ' require 'net/ldap'
con = Net::LDAP.new
con.host = 'localhost'
con.port = 389
con.auth 'cn=user,dc=example,dc=com', 'user'

if con.bind
  puts con.get_operation_result
else

  puts con.get_operation_result 
end '

Comment: @84104 I edited my question by adding code I used for binding. Yes, my current ACL is not a good idea. I used this as just a sample code to check how users can login. Once I'm able to fix that I will change ACL code.